# Why my view is not displayed. Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a learning project, I can't figure out why my view is not showing on localhost.
I am saving those html files in main\resource\template
but still the html file is not rendered instead a string is showing up on the screen.

My Controllers

```
package com.blog.test.controllers;

import com.blog.test.entities.Users;
import com.blog.test.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Home {

    @Autowired
     UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @GetMapping("index")
    public String showHome(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("registration")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        Users users = new Users();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "registration";
    }

    }
```

my entities

```
package com.blog.test.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Table(name = "POSTS")
@Entity
public class Posts {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int post_id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Users users;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private String Title;




    public Posts(){}

    public Posts(int post_id, Users users, LocalDateTime created) {
        this.post_id = post_id;
        this.users = users;
        this.created = created;
    }
}
and 
package com.blog.test.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

@Table(name = "USERSDETAILS")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "users")
    private LoginInfo loginInfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    List<Posts> userPosts;

    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime created;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(int userid, LoginInfo loginInfo, String name, LocalDateTime created) {
        this.userid= userid;
        this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
        this.name = name;
        this.created = created;
    }
}
and 
package com.blog.test.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "LOGININFODETAILS")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoginInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int loginId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Users users;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public LoginInfo(int loginId, String username, String password) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public LoginInfo() {

    }
}
```

and my pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my html files are

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div>
    <a th:href="@{/registration}">Go to Registration Form</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT nothing is coming up when I hit the localhost:8082\index
where do I get wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG9Bc.jpg)

Comment: I didn't read everything but \@RestController doesn't look right to me try \@Controller
and can you share the project layout

Comment: B.T.W you are using parent pom so I don't think you need to specify the thymeleaf version

Answer (score 0):

RestController annotation will return the json response not HTML or JSP.

@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody.

@RestController is used to create RESTful web services. For returning html or jsp, annotate the controller class with @Controller annotation.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`

```
 @Controller
  public class Home {
    
        @Autowired
         UsersRepository usersRepository;
    
        @GetMapping("index")
        public String showHome(Model model) {
            return "index";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("registration")
        public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
            Users users = new Users();
            model.addAttribute("users", users);
            return "registration";
        }
    
        }
```

`Difference` between `@Controller` and  `@RestController`  is where we use when we need `JSON_RESPONSE`  which we use in `REST API`.
and `@Controller` will return `HTML and JS` e.g `View`